# Examples of "Great subjective questions"

Tags: discussion, subjective-topics, list-question, reference

From EL&U Helpcenter about [asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun
>
> For more detail, read about our [guidelines for great subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and blog post about how [real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

So what are some examples of constructive subjective questions that are allowed on EL&U? (or What are some examples of great subjective questions on EL&U?)

This question and answers would be a great reference.

**Note:** It can be same as great primarily-opinion based questions also (which are exceptionally good and previously allowed)

**Note2:** The below meta post is related also and there are some general examples in it: 
[A look at question quality](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/a-look-at-question-quality)

---

<sub>Subnote: I could not be sure if this question is appropriate also. I searched for other questions that might ask for examples but I could not find and I also checked tags that might be used for this kind of question.</sub>

Comment: Many of our single-word-request questions are quite subjective. Those tend to be really popular among some of the users.

Comment: [These](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition) [are](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76578/why-is-american-english-so-wedded-to-the-subjunctive) [but](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139753/is-there-an-acceptable-corresponding-negative-to-well-off) [a](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95316/is-pregnant-couple-proper-terminology) [few](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place/143790#143790). Far from the best, but a few I found for you.

Comment: Great question, thanks for asking.